# C3.js - Add right padding to Timeseries charts

Tags: javascript, charts, padding, c3, c3.js

I was wondering if there is a way to add right padding to a `Timeseries` chart on `C3.js`.

As you can see on this [example](http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html) from C3js.org, the date labels are getting cut off on the right. Or see following picture:
[image]

Comment: To solve this, I just add CSS to the element. Alternatively, just make the container that much wider than the chart itself or set `overflow: visible`.

Comment: A CSS property... The label is being drawn, it's just being clipped. So the containing div needs to show overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the option padding > right, like so

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    padding: {
        right: 20
    },
    data: {
    ...
```

---

From the documentation at http://c3js.org/reference.html#padding-right

> **padding.right**
>
> The padding on the right of the chart.
>
> Default: undefined

Comment: This worked. Be careful! Add padding the way @potatopeelings did. Don't add it inside `x-axis`, otherwise it won't work

Comment: The x-axis is a time series so the padding is count as milliseconds not as pixels. There is an open issue in the repository: https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1128